# how can a php soap server listen to a soap client c program?

Tags: php

My soap client is working fine and I'm looking for a way send data from soap client (written in c) to soap server written in php. 
What I know the basic initiate in php like the following

```
$soapServer= new SoapServer("test.wsdl"); 
$soapServer->setClass('myClass');
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$soapServer->handle();
```

But exactly how can I let php "listen" and receive data from soap client?
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generate a SOAP server, you have to define your functions:

You make a function

```
<?php
function getItemCount($upc){
//in reality, this data would be coming from a database
$items = array('12345'=>5,'19283'=>100,'23489'=>234);
return $items[$upc];
}
?>
```

Now add that function to your SOAP service

```
<?php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // disabling WSDL cache
$server = new SoapServer("inventory.wsdl");
$server->addFunction("getItemCount");
$server->handle();
?>
```

That function getItemCount is added to your SOAP service

To test this with a client:

```
<?php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // disabling WSDL cache
$client = new SoapClient("http://[path to the service]/inventory.wsdl");
$return = $client->getItemCount('12345');
print_r($return);
?>
```

For more information and details http://jimmyzimmerman.com/blog/2007/02/soap-server-with-php5-part3-the-glue-code.html